# React native es5 vs es6 explanation request

Tags: reactjs, comparison, ecmascript-6, native

I'm about to start learning react native but in the start line, I'm confused which way is the better or recommended. JS has modified so frequently! I was trying to get some comparison with explanation but no success so far. (very hard to recognize..)
Can somebody give me a small explanation which one is es5 and es6? Some advice for a newbie? I have found several tutorial in this field, but just increased my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES5 vs ES6 has to do with Javascript in general and is not specific to react or react native. Es6 is a newer standard for Javascript than ES5. However because ES6 isn't supported everywhere, oftentimes things like babel have to be used to convert ES6 into ES5.

This link should have more info on the differences:
http://benmccormick.org/2015/09/14/es5-es6-es2016-es-next-whats-going-on-with-javascript-versioning/

As for how it will affect you in React and React-Native it has to do with the new features available in ES6 such as lambda functions, better class support and stuff like that.

A common example is the difference between

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({...functions...});
```

and

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{...functions...}
```

There's a little more  info on that here: https://daveceddia.com/react-es5-createclass-vs-es6-classes/

Good luck :).